# How to post list of model on controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

There is 1 form on which i will ask for Academic Details for :

- Graduation
- Post Graduation(Masters)
- Professional Qualification.

So far any user say UserId="1" **3 entries will be created in my AcademicMaster each for bachelor,Master(Post Graduation) and Professional Qualification**.

My Database AcademicMaster table fields and datamodel:

```
Id,Qualification(GraduationCourses),Acheievement,UserId
```

View Model:

```
public class AcademicViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Graduation     Graduation{ get; set; }
    public virtual PostGraduation PostGraduation{ get; set; }
    public virtual ProfessionalQualification ProfessionalQualification{ get; set; }
}

public class Graduation
{
    public string BachelorQualification { get; set; }
    public string BachelorAchievement { get; set; }
}
public class PostGraduation
{
    public string MasterQualification { get; set; }
    public string MasterAchievement { get; set; }
}
public class ProfessionalQualification
{
    public string ProfessionalQualifications { get; set; }
}
```

So my View is like this:

```
@model AcademicViewModel
@{
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> graduationList = ViewBag.GraduationList;
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> postGraduationList = ViewBag.PostGraduationList;
}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="row">
        Bachelors
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Graduation.Qualification, graduationList)
    </div>
    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Graduation.Achievement)

    <div class="row">
        MASTERS
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PostGraduation.Qualification, postGraduationList)
    </div>
    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.PostGraduation.Achievement)
    <div class="row">
        PROFESSIONAL QUALIFITCATION
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.ProfessionalQualification.ProfessionalQualifications)
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
}
```

This is my Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyController(AcademicViewModel model)
{
    //Actions
}
```

So is my View Model structure appropriate and how to create 3 entries in AcademicMaster Table??

Comment: Bit hard to understand what your wanting to do. What is the model in the view you have shown? (it has properties `Qualification` and `Achievement` but none of the models you have shown have those properties). And your creating multiple dropdownlists and textareas for the same property (only the first one of each will be bound to your model

Comment: @StephenMuecke:See the Model in my updated question and i just want to create 3 entries in my Academic Master for Bachelor,Master and professional qualification.so i just want to know how to do this

Comment: Still where is the `Qualification` and `Achievement` in you model `AcademicViewModel`

Comment: Still not making sense. For `ProfessionalQualification` you only have one property whereas the others have 2 (what gets stored in the `Acheievement` field of your table). But more to the point, why do you have  one `AcademicMaster` table instead of tables for each? And if its only one table, how could you possibly know whether the entry is `Graduation`, `PostGraduation` or `Professional`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke:See my updated question and at each level like Bachelor,Master Achievement would be any quiz competiton or any talent examination awards and yeah you definetly have a point so can you give me any solution of how to manage this with only 1 table??

Comment: @Learning can you try to build you scenario in this fiddle (https://dotnetfiddle.net/IHsPc2)

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have 3 tables? But if you want only one, then you should have another field to identify if its relating to one of the 3 categories

Comment: @StephenMuecke:Can you post some solution with some changes in my viewmodel too if any

Comment: Based on one table or three?

Comment: @StephenMuecke:Sorry table would be 1 only.

Comment: @StephenMuecke:Yeah sure.No problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will start by saying that having one table may not be the best choice (what happens if later you start adding additional properties which may be applicable to `Graduation` that are not applicable to `Professional` - for example `YearOfGraduation` - you could end up with a huge number of fields, many of which may have `null` values.

However, if you want one table, then at least add another field so that you can identify if the data is related to `Graduation`, `PostGraduation` or `Professional`. The associated data model for the `AcademicMasters` table would be

```
public class AcademicMaster
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Type { get; set; } // may be an enum?
  public string Qualification { get; set; }
  public string Achievement { get; set; }
  public int UserID { get; set; }
}
```

Side note: It might be better to use an `enum` for the `Type` property

```
public enum AcademicType
{
  Graduation,
  PostGraduation,
  Professional
}
```

There does not seem to be any need to your current `Graduation`, `PostGraduation` and `ProfessionalQualification` models and your view model should be

```
public class AcademicViewModel
{
  public string GraduationQualification { get; set; }
  public string GraduationAchievement { get; set; }
  public string PostGraduationQualification { get; set; }
  public string PostGraduationAchievement { get; set; }
  public string ProfessionalAchievement { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GraduationList { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PostGraduationList { get; set; }
}
```

Side notes: Its not clear what your current `ProfessionalQualifications` property is - does that get assigned to the `Qualification` field or the `Acheievement` field in the database? Since your using a view model, then it should include the `SelectList`'s rather that using `ViewBag`.

Then your view will be

```
@model AcademicViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  <h2>Graduation</h2>
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.GraduationQualification, Model.GraduationList)
  @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.GraduationAchievement)
  ... // repeat for PostGraduation and Professional
  <input type="submit" value="Save">
}
```

And the POST method would be

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyController(AcademicViewModel model) // should be named Create?
{
  var userID = ....
  AcademicMaster graduation = new AcademicMaster
  {
    Type = AcademicType.Graduation,
    Qualification = model.GraduationAchievement,
    Achievement = model.GraduationAchievement,
    UserId = userID;
  };
  db.AcademicMasters.Add(graduation);
  // Repeat for PostGraduation and Professional
  db.SaveChanges();
  // redirect?
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for this details ans.Thanks.it really helped